# Sign In/Sign out issue in Magento 2.4

Tags: phtml

I have a Sign in Link that successfully changes to sign out when a user is logged in, and successfully logs the user out when I click sign out. However, I ran into a bug. When Signed in, if I go to any other page or link, The Sign out link changes back to Sign in, Yet I show i am still signed in on the user dashboard.

Here is the code in my phtml file that switches the Sign in to Sign out.

```
<li class="nav-links">
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
?>  <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("customer/account/logout");?>"><?php echo __("Sign Out");
} else {
?>  <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("customer/account/login");?>"><?php echo __("Sign 
In/Register");?></a>
<?php }
?>
</li>
```

Also, When clicking the hamburger menu to the right of the log out link when signed in, The hamburger menu logs me out. Here is the code for the menu button.

```
<button class="hamburger"><?php echo __("☰")?></button> <button class="cross">˟</button>
```

I am trying to get the logout button to stay visible no matter what page i visit after being signed in. There must be something i am not seeing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento pages are full page cached, so that's the problem with the Magento\Customer\Model\Session

For determining if user is logged use this class and run the method isLoggedIn ;)

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as HttpContext;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class Customer implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /** @var HttpContext */
    private $httpContext;

    /**
     * @param HttpContext $httpContext
     */
    public function __construct(
        HttpContext $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isLoggedIn(): bool
    {
        return (bool)$this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }
}
```

Using object manager directly is considered a bad pratice.

Hope this helps you a bit.

@updated so it's a viewModel now.

Comment: where do I use that class? app/code/vendor/module/Helper?

Comment: Hard to answer that, where do you need, but in general, yeah app/code/{vendor}/{module} will be the spot where the class should be placed, 
You can make it as a ViewModel, and then use it in your blocks, or inject this into your block class if you use one.
I will upgrade the answer and make that the class is a ViewModel so you can then inject it easier into any block you need.

Comment: ok sorry I am somewhat new to magento but it is making sense now. Thanks.